# Convert jar to exe using Ubuntu. Cyrillic symbols are not shown

Tags: java, ubuntu, cyrillic, launch4j

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. And now I have to conver .jar file to .exe file. I tried to use launch4j. It works very nice, but now I have a problem with cyrillic symbols because of it. When I tried to run .jar, there was not any problem like this. What can be used instead of launch4j in Ubuntu to solve this problem with symbols?

Comment: Do you mean executable or Windows exe file? On Windows the default charset is not UTF-8 - this may be the problem.

Comment: I mean Windows exe. How is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: Check your project. Everywhere you read characters (e.g. BufferedReader, InputStreamReader,...) from a file or a stream make sure you explicitly set the charset to UTF-8.

Comment: No problem with this. And when I run jar, the cyrillic symbols work normaly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wine to run .exe in Ubuntu? it is probably the cause of your problem, try to run your .exe on windows and see if it still happening.